# Ethernet driver for Motherboard H410M H V2 for Ubuntu version 18.04

Tags: 18.04

When I install ubuntu 18.04 the LAN can't detect the motherboard GIGABYE H410M H V3. Can anyone help me.. thanks

Comment: Why are you installing a release with less than a year of support left?

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu! Please edit your question and include the output of the following command `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3`

Comment: As of now my program on this version.